# what is meaning of action="/echo/html/" ?

Tags: html, ajax

```
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">
action="/echo/html/"
```

Can anyone tell me what this will do? It is used for AJAX in my reference code.

Comment: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: It's just a "clean" uri. On the server it probably gets rewritten to something like `/scripts/foo.php?param1=echo&param2=html` or whatever. No way to tell, because that sort of rewrite is rarely made visible to the client-side of things.

Comment: are you using a framework with Controller/Models/Views?

Comment: According to @j08691's link, It seems to be a dummy AJAX controller that just spits back what you send it. For use in testing AJAX functionality.

Comment: `ajax` is not a valid attribute of `form`

Answer (score 0):

Without any Javascript on the page, if that form tag is properly formed and closed and includes a submit button, then clicking on the button will submit the form data as a POST to the route `/echo/html`.

However, the `ajax=true` bit implies that Javascript code on the page is going to handle form submission.  That JS code may respect the action there and submit the form to that route, or it may completely overwrite it with another route.  There's no way of knowing without knowing more about the JS code.

So it may be functional or it may be ignored depending on how the JS functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be for ajax. 
That completely depends on factors.

1. You need this URL mapped to some controlling logic.
   Eg. In java that can be well mapped servlet.
2. You need some JavaScript or any pre written plugin that make use of this form statement to make a Ajax call.

More details in question may help to answer properly.